# GA4 data streams and subdomains

Tags: subdomain, data, google-analytics-4

So i have this current setup with GA (universal analytics) where a subscription platform runs on a subdomain therefor we use a different view and different tracking code.

But with GA 4, i was wondering since the context is both our main website wouldn't it be just as fine to run an additional Data Stream so as to track everything within the same property both main site and subdomain site where the subscription platform runs on? (ie think of it as a mini ecommerce)

Or is it still better to run a different GA4 property for both main site and a subdomain of that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to "Analytics Maniac", for this use case its enough to use the same measurement id on the same property. Even having another data stream isn't required.

**Reference**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7laoCJcnqGk
```

Comment: How do I see how many people are on each subdomain?